# How to set the view un focusable android?

Tags: android

How to completely make a view off to focus state? I am adding these parameters in the xml but with the keyboard still able to focus the view.

What I have tried till now;

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

For instance I got 3 views. I want to set View2 unfocusable so if I use keyboard and focus View1 after switch to another one View3 will be in focus and View2 will be ignored..

How can I do that? Any solutions?

Comment: How do you switch to another one?

Comment: @JimRhodes with the help of hard keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you dont want the other views to be used when you are using one .
In the onClickListener of each View , you can set the other two to be unusable .This function could do the trick .

```
//Kotlin Code
private fun setImageViewStatus(view: View, value: Boolean) {
        view.apply {
            isEnabled = value
            isClickable = value
        }
    }
```

You can replace view with anything of your choice .

Answer (score 0):

In your XML for `View1` try adding a property for `nextFocusDown`. For example if the ID of `View3` is `View3` add the following to the XML for `View1`:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/View3"
```